# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter no me funcionan los botones

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy creando una app de radio, pero cuando quiero que funcionen  mis botones de *play* y *pause* con `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, solo aparece el de *play* y no cambia a *pause*.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
if NSClassFromString("MPNowPlayingInfoCenter") != nil {
    let songInfo: [String:AnyObject] = [
            MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Trasnmisión en vivo ",
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Expande tv",
           ]

    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo
}
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    print("Receiving remote control events\n")
} catch {
    print("Audio Session error.\n")
}

@IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    toggle()
}

func toggle() {
    if RadioPlayer.sharedInstance.currentlyPlaying() {
        pauseRadio()
    } else {
        playRadio()
    }
}

func playRadio() {
    RadioPlayer.sharedInstance.play()
    playButton.setTitle("Pause radio", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png")!, forState: .Normal)
    print("Play")
}

func pauseRadio() {
    RadioPlayer.sharedInstance.pause()
    playButton.setTitle("Play radio", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png")!, forState: .Normal)
    print("Pause")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente lo que te está faltando es implementar el método `remoteControlReceived(with:)`, que se llama cuando hay una acción en el *info center*.

```
func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let remoteEvent = event, remoteEvent.type == .remoteControl else {
        return
    }

    switch (remoteEvent.subtype) {
    case .remoteControlPause:
        // ...
    case .remoteControlPlay:
        // ...
    case .remoteControlStop:
        // ...
    default: break
    }
}
```